# Doesn't upvotes received after getting voted down the rep-cap yield any reputation?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

> `Wow! New Badges on SO - there's more to work for now!!`

I hit the rep cap today with an accepted answer that took me to 202 for the day (and thought I got one step closer to the new `Epic` badge).

Afterwards I received a down vote and two up-votes in god only knows what order and I ended up at 199. Then I down-voted one answer and that took me down to 198. All is fine till now and I thought next up-vote will take me back to the cap. But to my (not so pleasant) surprise, the next up-vote was treated as if I had already hit the cap and yielded no votes. I've included a screenshot showing the last stillborn vote.

Is this how rep-cap actually work - won't you get any reputation from up-votes once you hit the cap, even if your net rep for the day was brought down to less than 200 by down votes at the time the up-vote was cast?

Would this be fixed in a future rep recalculation and/or **counted towards Epic badge?**

[:( http://lh5.ggpht.com/_dMvpiHJOOxw/Sx0jz9_gBEI/AAAAAAAAAVE/CPo-ylkA8E8/s576/meta2.png](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_dMvpiHJOOxw/Sx0jz9_gBEI/AAAAAAAAAVE/CPo-ylkA8E8/s576/meta2.png)

Comment: Duplicate (several times over)

Comment: This is just how it works. BTW - you might want to be a little careful revealing exactly how you voted...

Comment: @chris Searched found some of them - should have done that before posting though. Anyways mine have freehand circles and all ;)

Comment: @Dominic didn't understand that warning - if you are referring to revealing the fact that I down-voted that particular question, I've put a comment to that post before down voting.

Comment: @Chris my concern is not those two rep points - I was wondering if today would be counted towards the new rep-cap badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsequent upvotes will counteract previous downvotes **received** up to the daily reputation cap.

Downgives **given** will always cost you 1 and count against your daily rep cap (so handing out 3 means you can gain 197 rep that day through upvotes received).

Comment: So two down-votes given in the day means maximum rep possible for that day is 198 (unless I get accepted afterwards)?

Comment: And again - would this 198 count towards rep-cap badges?

Comment: if downvoting does mean you lose a day towards a badge as you can't hit the cap, incidence of downvoting may well plummet

Comment: Well I think Jeff is the only one who can clarify the exact workings of this but I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: Even if yesterday count towards the badge, that would only be my 6th day. Miles to go before I sleep.

Answer (score 5):

Now that accepted answers and bounties are *truly* immune from the rep cap, not just occasionally chronologically immune depending on when they arrive, this should be fixed.

Comment: @Jeff, can you throw us a link that explains this.  I must have missed that post.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/