# How do I audit my reputation?

Tags: support, faq, reputation, reputation-audit

If I am concerned that my reputation score is incorrect, how can I audit it, or get a report of a detailed breakdown of my reputation?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: I'm favouriting this now to use in many upcoming close votes for support requests regarding reputation and statistics.

Comment: I like the smiley in the end of the report.

Comment: in your reputation tab, at the end there is a checkbox of ` show removed posts` just tick it to know the removed posts :)

Comment: @Lucifer:http://stackoverflow.com/users/869233/sarooptrivedi?tab=reputation

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi i can't see your removed posts, at present i do not have that privileges

Comment: @Lucifer: That's a wonder for me too. They are not show any -ve deduction.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Make sure you are logged in, and visit:

```
https://sitename.com/reputation
```

For example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
- https://cooking.stackexchange.com/reputation
- https://serverfault.com/reputation
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/reputation
- https://superuser.com/reputation
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation

This will give you a detailed audit / report of your reputation over time, reflecting the current voting values. It will look something like this:

```
 2     29812 (2)
-- 2009-11-15 rep +245  = 28647     
 2     29877 (10)
 3     29886 (-2)
 1     29877 (15)
 2     29886 (10)
 2     27958 (7)
 2     29905 [0]
 1     29905 (15)
 3     29884 (-2)
 2     29521 (2)
 2     31021 (5)
 2     29878 [0]
 9     28065 (550)
-- 2009-11-16 rep +275  = 28922     
 1     29915 (15)
 3     29882 (-2)
```

<sub>note that this is not an actual, valid report, just an example that I kind of cut and pasted into</sub>

The **first number** is the vote type, where common vote types are:

- 1 = accepted answer (to or from you)
- 2 = upvote (to you)
- 3 = downvote (to or from you)
- 4 = penalty for post flagged as offensive
- 8 = bounty grant (from you)
- 9 = bounty award (to you)
- 12 = penalty for post flagged as spam
- 16 = edit suggestion approved

The **second number** is the post ID that the vote was on. Remember that votes on community wiki posts do *not* generate rep, so those votes will not appear here. (Note that some vote types like offensive, spam, and bounties apply to any post regardless of its community wiki status)

The **third number** is the value of the vote. Note that the value may be capped if you reach the daily upvote reputation limit. If the value is capped, it will appear in brackets like `[3]` so.

The **date boundaries** are printed whenever your reputation changed in a given day(s). It contains the current date, the amount your rep changed (up or down) since the last time, and the total amount of rep you have earned to date.

<strike>At the bottom of the page, there is a button that says **Trigger Reputation Recalc**.  This will force the reputation value stored in the system to be recalculated based on the audit, correcting any errors.  Your reputation may change significantly if you have many posts that have been deleted or if many upvotes have been reverted after reaching the +200 cap.  Since this can be demanding on the servers, and *recalcs are normally reserved for gross errors or reputation scoring changes*, a recalc can only be performed once every 24 hours; for more information, see [Self-instigated rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/).  Note that this is no longer required as [the system now accurately keeps track of reputation changes caused by events such as deletion of posts or users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes).</strike>

As of December 2013, there is no "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button anymore. Recalc is performed automatically only, in case of reputation inconsistency that does not resolve itself please file a [new bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug,reputation).

Comment: This is a great new feature by the way.

Comment: @Jeff: Unexpected token ':)' while parsing the rep audit file. End of file expected.

Comment: @Jeff -- the report doesn't seem to jibe with my experience.  My sense is that (except on weekends) I hit the rep cap more often than not.  The report shows that this is far from the case. Is there anyway you could change the output format (to JSON, say) so that I could load it up more easily in a plotting package and visualize it.  I'd be ok with adding a parameter to the url to get an alternate format: http://stackoverflow.com/users/rep-report?format=json

Comment: @tvanfosson: That may happen because where previously you might have been hitting the rep-cap due to accepted answers awarded early in the day, for the new rep cap you actually need 20 upvotes. Accepted answers are completely ignored (and so are bounites, but those are rare).

Comment: @Daniel -- the thing I'm see is more <200 days than I expected.  Maybe I have just gotten over the obsession with hitting the rep cap and not know it yet.  That's why I'd like to graph the results and see how it changes over time -- and why I'd like the results in JSON or XML or something so I don't have to create a custom parser to get at the data.  It should be relatively easy to just serialize as JSON rather than HTML in the action if you get a format parameter -- I do this all the time  (see http://launchpad.uiowa.edu/plot/bysection vs http://launchpad.uiowa.edu/plot/bysection?format=json)

Comment: @tvan I think this is an unavoidable side effect of full immunity to the rep cap for bounties and accepted answers -- they simply don't count at all in the "have I reached my daily rep cap" calculation, only upvotes on non cwiki questions do...

Comment: "because the processing requires that it be walked in forward order" joke? :)

Comment: For Super User rep recalc, the very *first* line says `total votes: 575`.  I know this is not my total votes I have given others, because it is a lot higher than that (3455).  Is this how many votes other users have bestowed on my posts?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I'm too lazy to do the full calculation, but it appears that the total at the bottom of the page does not subtract points for any days that you earned *negative* reputation.  In my case, on Apple.SE, my rep is 2400.  The /reputation page says **total rep 2406**.  If I look through the breakdown, there are 5 days where I had negative rep, totaling 6 points.

Comment: even more interesting is that I clicked "trigger reputation recalc", and now my rep jumped to 2406 on the main site.

Comment: What does it mean when it says "[0]" as third number? I have such things quite often, and I don't understand it. Doesn't it mean it earned no reputation? How can that happen?

Comment: @Johannes: *If the value is capped, it will appear in brackets like `[3]` so.* Hence: you've reached the daily reputation limit, and are not getting all (or even: none) reputation for that action.

Comment: Oh noes.  I hit recalc and lost about 100 rep.  There should be a warning on that thing...

Comment: @studiohack I am also wondering what does this value come from. I asked it here: [What does “total votes” mean in the /reputation page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264708/209901)

Comment: Does this show reputation loss due to removed posts? I see one in my reputation tab, but not in <S.E. site>/reputation. Any idea?

Comment: What do the `-- <date> rep 0` lines mean? Have someone retracted a vote?
([this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82652/578924) is not correct at all...)

Answer (score 35):

I've seen a few people confused about the new rep-reports, so I will try to give an example of both question-vote changes and daily-cap changes in one fell swoop:

```
-- 2009-06-29 rep +129  = 986  
 2   1061283 (5)    # question upvote, used to be +10, now +5
 2   1061283 (5)
 1   1061350 (2)    # I accepted an answer
 2   1061283 (5)
 2   1061283 (5)
 2   1061380 (10)   # upvote on my answer
 2   1061660 (10)
 2   1061660 (10)
 2   1061660 (10)
 2   1060244 (10)
 2   1061380 (10)
 1   1061660 (15)   # someone accepted my answer
 2   1061660 (10)
 1   1061380 (15)   # someone accepted my answer
 2   1061660 (10)
 2   1061660 (10)
 3           (-1)   # I will never tell you who I downvoted!
 2   1062027 (10)
 2   1061660 (10)
 2   1062860 (10)
 3           (-1)
 2   1062894 (10)
 2   1062894 (10)
 2   1060376 (10)
 2   1062860 (10)
 2   1062996 (10)
 1   1062996 (15)   # someone accepted my answer
 2   1060376 (10)
 2   1046207 [2]    # upvote on my answer, 2 points "fill" daily cap
 2   1061283 [0]    # upvote on my answer, after hitting the daily cap :(((
 2   1060376 [0]
 2   1062860 [0]
 2   1047514 [0]
 2   1047514 [0]
 2   1062860 [0]
-- 2009-06-30 rep +247  = 1233
```

```
Involved in daily rep-cap:
Question upvotes   4x  5 =  20
Answer upvotes    25x 10 = 250
They downvoted     0x -2 =   0
I downvoted        2x -1 =  -2
                           ---
                           268
Apply rep cap:             200

Not involved in daily rep-cap:
I accepted         1x  2 =   2
They accepted      3x 15 =  45
Arr, bounty        0x  _ =   0
                           ---
                            47

Total rep gained that day: 247
```

I don't know if all of this is intended or will be how it is in the end, but that's how I interpret my whole rep-report now.  It makes sense of the numbers I've seen.  In particular, the real rep is counted in a linear fashion, and I've stripped that away in my table.

Comment: Rep lost by own downvotes will never be filled to rep cap. Only rep lost by others' downvotes will.

Answer (score 17):

Usually, the reputation tab on your profile is good enough for audits, just that a few things are hidden by default. Here's how to show them:

1. Go to the reputation tab on your profile
2. Click the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom

[image]

You should see an account of wherever you lost rep due to deleted posts, etc (i.e, non-public stuff).

Comment: IMO "show removed posts" should be put at the top instead of the bottom -- it's too hard to be seen.

Answer (score 7):

In response to [dmckee's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43012#43012):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -nw
use strict;
our ($caps, $capped);
++$caps if /\[/ && !$capped++;
$capped = 0 if /^--/;
END {print "Days capped = $caps\n"}
```

If that script is correct, then after the new metrics come in, I only need to cap my rep twice more to get my Epic badge. :-D (On SO, not on meta. :-P)

Answer (score 6):

In response to tvan's comment, I whipped up a really-weird-audit-format to JSON converter in PHP.
Right now it will output something like this:

```json
[
   {
      "date":"bonuses ",
      "rep":""
   },
   {
      "date":"2009-05-18",
      "rep":"10"
   },
   {
      "date":"2009-05-26",
      "rep":"25"
   },
   {
      "date":"blahblahblah",
      "rep":"youcannotseethisblah"
   }
]
```

I might update it to include more detailed information (poke me enough and I'll do it, I promise :D)

You can find the source code [here](http://gist.github.com/339753) on gist.github.
Put that in a directory, then take your audit and put it in a file called `audit.txt` in the same directory. Run the script and you have your JSON. (If you look at the script, it can also be EASILY changed to output XML :D)

PS: Run the script and pass in debug as a GET parameter will get you debug info.