# Daily reputation limit just broke...?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit

I had "maxed out" daily rep on stackoverflow yesterday night (Pacific Daylight Time) -- except for acceptances, as usual.  (i.e., 00:00 to 07:00 or so, UTC).

Then suddenly this (PST) morning I noticed I'm getting rep again for upvotes I'm receiving on my answer.  On my "reputation" tab I clearly see upvotes received 6 to 9 hours ago (midnight to 3 AM PST -> 7:00 to 10:00 UTC) with no rep gain, but also upvotes received 4 hours ago and later (4:30 AM PST and later -> 10:30 UTC and later) which *do* indicate rep gain.  What's up?  I hadn't heard of impending rule changes wrt the daily rep limit (only of one impending change wrt the weight of upvotes on questions) -- is it a bug...?

**Edit**: as the accepted answer makes clear, there **were** indeed rule changes (for the better, it seems;-) - and indeed my daily rep seems to have maxed out again now (at the nicer new level;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are seeing the changes/bug fixes mentioned here:

[How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43008#43008)

Comment: **YES**!  That's definitely it -- not sure why it wasn't mentioned on the blog/podcast (guess they weren't too proud of a bug fix;-).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The daily limit is not based on your local time, but rather on UTC (what used to be called Greenwich Mean Time). Thus, depending on your area's daylight savings time practices, your rep cap probably expired around 5 PM. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone) for more information on Pacific Time, and here for more information on [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utc).

Comment: Yes, I should have made it clear that I'm quite aware of that, I was just too lazy to keep translating PST times to UTC.  5pm is SO day beginning/end for me on PST (was 4pm since recently as we were on PDT), and that doesn't affect my question.

Answer (score 0):

Days, and thus the daily reputation cap, are defined in UTC.

The day ends at Midnight UTC, more commonly known as:

- 4:00PM PST
- 5:00PM MST
- 6:00PM CST
- 7:00PM EST

Notice these are **Standard Times** not, **Daylight Savings Times**. Therefore if you are in the Pacific Standard Timezone, and you post something at 2PM, at 5PM, it will be considered yesterday. If you get an upvote at 5PM when you hit the daily cap at 2PM, it is technically a new day, and you will get the reputation for the upvote.