# Figure out how many rep points you're going to lose from your questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Has anyone come up with a way to count the totals and do a recalc projection?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your [post-apocalyptic rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/rep-report) today. (Last line.)

Comment: Woot, beat the closers by -16 seconds!

Comment: Thnaks! Looks like I'll loose about 2000 rep. :(