# Daily reputation limit (greatest bugfix evah [sic]): do Epic/Legendary change?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

Just a short post to say thanks for fixing what is my #1 most irksome bug: the inconsistencies in the rep system about timing of votes, accepted answers and bounties. Wasn't expecting it; at least I didn't see anything about it in the recent post about question upvote reweighting but maybe I missed it.

This made about ~7k difference to me (93k => 100k).

Does this affect the Epic/Legendary badges in some way?

*Edit:* Let me clarify that by saying that I *expect* that badges won't be retroactively removed from those that already have them. What I think would be helpful would be a clarification on what hitting the rep cap means in the context of these badges.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff said following on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#comment-97337) comment

> I think this is an unavoidable side
>   effect of full immunity to the rep cap
>   for bounties and accepted answers --
>   they simply **don't count at all** in the
>   "have I reached my daily rep cap"
>   calculation, only upvotes on non cwiki
>   questions do

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it would, but I think the way the badges work is that you don't get them taken away (mostly, I believe some beta badges got removed when it was changed so that you had to be active during the beta).  What typically happens is you just don't get another one when you qualify for it if a previous one had been invalidated.  In the case of badges awarded just once, this would be moot since the only time it would be detected is when it is being awarded again.

Comment: You're quite right about not getting badges taken away. Jeff has stated that repeatedly. I guess I should edit to clarify that.

Comment: I believe this is a special case since those badges are fundamentally rep-dependent and the rep system has undergone a dramatic change. Qualification for those badges should be re-evaluated IMO.

Comment: Chances are it's very few people that would lose it, even if implemented to do that, but I'd rather see the precedent set of not removing badges, since that seems to match Jeff's repeated statements they won't be taken away.