# Rep Repo Man is mocking us!

Tags: feature-request, fun, reputation-audit

This is unacceptable! I'm being **mocked** and I can't do anything about it. Looking over the rep report I see this at the end:

[image: How dare he openly mock me like this????]

How dare he smile at me? I'm losing 427 points of my hard earned rep! Outrageous!!!! The nerve of the guy, staring at me and smiling while I suffer...

I propose a change. Make the smiley better reflect my feelings and comfort me in these dark days.

[image: There, there. We'll get through this together]

Comment: Voting to close as exact duplicate of this comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation#comment-97143

Comment: `** total rep 12 >:(  o_O  <(**<) (>**<) (>**)>`

Comment: When I saw the title, I had to change it to Repo Man http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repo!_The_Genetic_Opera

Comment: Be thankful he's only mocking you and not passing judgment on your score. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Bill that would be just too much!

Comment: OK, you're all officially crazy.

Comment: @Marc that's a good thing, right? When I asked this question I was a bit fed up with all the "wher my rep go?!!1?"

Comment: @alex - around here? It is the necessary entry criteria (unless your question starts with "migrated from...")

Comment: Note to self: don't look over your history on Meta... I can't believe I actually asked this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GreaseMonkey Script

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/72481.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/72481)

Here is mine

```
....
** total rep 2494 :(
```

<sub>PS: Its a shame that, I don't know how to use jQuery with Content-Encoding: text/plain</sub>

EDIT: Now its show how many points you're going to lose. (need to install again)

```
...
** total rep 2524 (-16) :(
```

Comment: Due to lack of an official response, I'll consider your answer as the best one possible.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't been paying your late fees, and the [Repo Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repo!_The_Genetic_Opera) is repossessing your rep.

He just enjoys his work, that's why he is smiling.

Answer (score 1):

It will be fixed in 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: Really? Wow! I'll put a reminder to celebrate :)