# Attention MSO Users!

Tags: discussion

Meta will now be shutdown due to "Why did I lose rep questions?" for the next several weeks.

That is all.

Comment: Yeah, soz about that

Comment: @adam, no worries, that's why this site is here.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have gained 90 points on SO.  What's more, my rep-score page has a smiley face at the end, and that has brightened my day.  To whom may I direct my thanks and praise?

Comment: You'll upset other users about the smiley ! (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43218/rep-repo-man-is-mocking-us) ;-)

Comment: Your answer makes me feel so good. You gained 90 points and I lost over 2000. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

At least we survived the initial batch of questions. Now we just have to wait for the next 24 hours as people wake from sleep and start checking SOFU.

Comment: Aren't Mondays great anyway?

Comment: Some people sleep?

Comment: @amelvin Some people sleep, yes. Others actually do work, *gasp* and aren't on SOFU for 24/7. But obviously not Jon Skeet, despite what he claims.

Comment: I'm guessing that 'Jon Skeet' is actually the result of a mid-1980s cloning experiment; probably starring Michael J Fox.

Answer (score 1):

Well the rep change is sure to liven things up and its always good to shake up the system to see if it improves things.  The worst that can happen is that the change is hugely unpopular and counter-productive - at which point the change can be reversed.

The crunch will come if the change is hugely unpopular but beneficial!

But if the change has a positive impact on the site (I know that will be difficult to imagine if you've lost a bunch of rep - mines only gone down 19 as a result of the change) then everyone benefits regardless of short-term rep hurt.