# 42 rep gain with no downvotes and 5 upvotes - why?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501860/explaining-to-boss-why-we-need-to-avoid-horizontal-scroll/2501930#2501930) was just upvoted 5 times, with zero down-votes.

However, I only got 42 rep for it - based both on my total rep count I see (last up-vote changed the count by 2) and based on Summary/Recent Activity screen (shows 5/42 for that question).

However, I don't think I hit the daily cap, since my "recent" activity shows 42 reputation between 2010-03-23 14:34:29Z to 2010-03-23 23:59:59Z

Am I mis-understanding the timeframes for computing daily gap? (If I click on "Today" button it shows 253 rep, some of it from non-up-votes), Is that the reason?

Thx

Comment: Check your rep report at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation; example interpretation at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43046#43046.

Comment: @Gnome - thanks! I didn't realize rep report is a permanent feature, my impression was that it was a one-time thing to estimate your change in rep due to recalc.

Comment: Time will tell if it's permanent or not, but I get the feeling the functionality is intended to stick around, even if the current format isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answer your question yourself. When you click the envelope, the default view doesn't show a whole day. You have to explicitly click on 'today' to get everything for 'today'.

So yes, you already hit the cap today and that's why you only got 2 rep for the last up-vote.

Comment: Was afraid that's the case :(