# Reputation calculation error: 5 upvotes / 0 downvotes = 42 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I have a strange error I got an upvote but I got only 2 rep for that:

[image: Something wrong here 42 rep for 5 upvotes]

As you can see I got 5 upvotes but just 42 rep. Could somebody explain that?

Well I read [42 rep gain with no downvotes and 5 upvotes - why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43690/42-rep-gain-with-no-downvotes-and-5-upvotes-why) but I got two days ago 252 rep and yesterday 245 which is less. So has this something to do with the day limit?

From the rep page:

```
 2  13549027 (10)
 2  13549027 (10)
...
 2  13549027 (10)
...
 2  13549027 (10)
 2  13549027 [2]
-- 2012-11-25 rep +245  = 5072
```

Comment: Don't forget that accepts and bounties don't count towards the 200 daily repcap.

Comment: That means I run into the daily repcap. I understand that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit the reputation cap, congratulations! You can only earn 200 points in a Stack Overflow day from votes. The +2 there was to compensate for a downvote you received earlier in the day.

Together with 3 accepted answers (which don't count against the cap) you received 245 points in total.

The day you made 252 points, you only received 190 points in upvotes and 60 in accepted answers. You had not yet reached the cap.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand how that limit works. I need to wait for the accept timeout.