# +8 Reputation for a question with +1upvote/0downvote: Why, it should be +10

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

For [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075317/649524) answer, i have got +8 Rep.

As per my understanding,

REP = +10 per upvote, -2 per downvote.

Why I have got +8?

[image]

Comment: You hit the reputation cap.

Comment: You got downvoted 4 times, which cost you 8 rep, so by the time you got your last vote of the day before hitting the reputation cap, it could only give you that 8 rep instead of the full 10 (because full 10 would've crossed the daily cap).

Comment: Why did you start unaccepting answers?

Comment: Seems duplicate of [Reputation-calculation-error-5-upvotes-0-downvotes-42](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156726/reputation-calculation-error-5-upvotes-0-downvotes-42-rep?rq=1)

Comment: @Chichiray Doesn't matter, that's the right of the person who asks questions, to accept/unaccept *as they please*.

Comment: @Jolly: sure :) But that he start doing it after hitting the rep cap suggests that he incorrectly thought that he could get per saldo more rep the next day when he accepts them again or something like that. Tilak: you won't lose rep by accepting them again. Accepted answers are immune to rep cap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only net 200 reputation per day from includes upvotes, downvotes, suggested edits, etc. So if you for some reason get downvoted 50 times, and upvoted 50 times, you will receive (-100 + 500) = maximum = 200 reputation for the day.

(you can get more from accepted answers/bounties, which are counted differently, which is why you had +215 for the day)

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/193412) for a much more detailed explanation of reputation.

Comment: Is it only upvotes or upvotes + downvotes? Is it only applicable on answers or also on questions?