# +8 Reputation in Top-Bar for Answer with +1upvote/0downvote

Tags: support, reputation, top-bar

I noticed I received an upvote to [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24272011/1796930), but the top-bar said that I had only recieved **+8** rep for the answer.

However, the drop-down menu indicated that I had in fact received **+10** rep for my answer:

[image: Rep Displayed in Top-bar]

Also, according to the [rep auditing link](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) (*see [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)*), it appears that I actually received **+10** rep:

```
... (prior records omitted for brevity)
 2  24272011 (10)
-- 2014-07-14 rep +10   = 1114      
-- 2014-07-16 rep 0     = 1114      
-- 2014-07-17 rep 0     = 1114      
-- 2014-07-21 rep 0     = 1114      
 2  24272011 (10)
-- 2014-07-22 rep +10   = 1124   

** rep today: 10
** rep this week (2014-07-20 - 2014-07-26): 10
...
```

And, my profile page also shows **+10** rep:

[image: Reputation tab of Profile Page]

A similar question ([+8 Reputation for a question with +1upvote/0downvote: Why, it should be +10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160728/259031)) has already been asked, but that user had hit the daily rep cap, which I haven't even come close to.

So, is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Go to your reputation page. Click the checkbox at the bottom - the one for "show removed posts". See anything for the 19th?

Comment: you could have been downvoted and then had the vote reversed before you opened up the menu.

Comment: @Oded you were right on the money - I had a post that was removed a few days ago. Thanks for your quick response! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh! Thanks to @Oded, now I see the issue. I had a post that was removed 3 days ago, but I didn't see that until I checked the **show removed posts** option at the bottom of the page:

[image: Reputation tab Profile Page]