# Losing my accepted-answer points on move?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, merged-questions

A question I answered, and my answer accepted, has been closed and now redirects to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c/2886589). My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c/2886589#2886589) thus moved under that question. I'd expect to have lost my accepted-answer points because my answer is no longer the accepted answer: there was another that was accepted earlier. So, now, in essence, I have 15 points for an accepted-answer that doesn't exist.

Bug, or feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation ([more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005)). It should show a number of 15 points (or so) less than your current score, meaning that you will lose the points on your next recalc.

Comment: What is that page?

Comment: @Wilhelm, more info [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005)