# What to do if a more accurate solution is answered on an already accepted question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change the chosen answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/is-it-possible-to-change-the-chosen-answer)

One of my question which is answered and also accepted, but after some day I got a more accurate answer. So I want to accept his answer and undo the previous acceptance.

can I do this? Or. I have to satisfy the more accurate answer only with a upvote.

If I can switch my accepted answer, then what happens to the 15 reputations given to the previous accepted answer? Will that reputations remains as it is or that will be deducted?

If the answer is "Yes the reputations will be deducted", then why, what is the mistake of that answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can change the accept.
Just click the 'accept' marker next to the new answer, and the accept switches to the new answer.
Of course there is nothing to keep you from upvoting either answer.

[image]

As is discussed in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50859/losing-my-accepted-answer-points-on-move), this will affect the reputation points of the person with the formerly accepted answer. The +15 points that he/she got for having his/her answer accepted, will be deducted again.

Comment: What is this with 12 and 8 upvotes without any answer?

Comment: I removed the answer text from the picture as it was not relevant.

Comment: But reputation should be deducted, if some mistake is done. What is that guys mistake if some other gives a good answer?

Comment: I have updated the picture.

Comment: @Chandra, only one answer can be the accepted answer. What a lot of people do if a new answer is provided is mark the new answer as the accepted answer, but don't up-vote it. That way you can up-vote the previous answer (if you hadn't already) and balance the rep out a little better, making the sting of un-accepting the original answer a bit less harsh. If you had already both up-voted and accepted the previous answer, this doesn't help much.

Answer (score 8):

You can switch the accepted answer at any time (just click the gray "accept" check mark next to the new answer).  If someone was motivated to provide a better answer then we encourage you to acknowledge that by accepting the *best* answer.  If the other (originally accepted) answer was extremely helpful to you and you want to give it a bonus, you can always go back and award a bounty to that answer when you have enough reputation.