# Regarding daily reputation cap for Epic & Legendary badges

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

Do I need to earn reputation of 200 points per day consecutively for 50 days and 150 days to earn the Epic and Legendary badges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the <kbd>Epic</kbd> badge, you need to hit the daily reputation cap on (at least) 50 days. I.e. you need to have 50 days in your SO history when you received at least 200 rep points. The days don't need to be consecutive though.

For the <kbd>Legendary</kbd> badge, the same rules apply, except that the limit is 150 instead of 50.

Note that you can check at the bottom of your [rep audit page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation), how many days you have reached the daily limit.

Comment: Is it 200rep points or actually hit the rep cap limitation? If you get rep from accepted answers and bounties you can get over 200rep and the limitation happens later.

Comment: @Martin, it is 200 rep points per day. Getting rep from accepts and bounties is not limited anyway.

Comment: Yes, I now that rep from accepts and bounties is not limited anyway. I read different infos about that that rep also doesn't count for the rep cap badges, so the 200 rep must be only from up-votes. Other posts say it doesn't matter how the 200 rep is achieved.

Comment: @Martin, when I received my Epic badge, I didn't have 50 upvotes-only rep-cap days, so it was the latter case for me. Obviously the rules may have changed since, although I doubt it - you should be able to find some news about such a change on the blog or here on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not consecutive.  I recently received the Epic badge on SO, and I can assure you I didn't break the limit on 50 consecutive days.

Comment: so what it mean "Hit the daily reputation cap on 50/150 days" with in the 50 days we need to hit the 200 reputation once ?

Comment: @Gobi no - every day for 50 days ( not necessarily back to back) you've to earn atleast 200 reputation to get the badge

Comment: thanxs jaay

so not back to back mean that we can get 200 points twice a day or once a week  until 50 days sorry if the question seems silly jaay