# Make all [faq] questions community-wiki

Tags: support, meta, community-wiki, meta-faq

I noticed a lot of FAQ questions are not marked as CW.

The official [FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) clearly states that all faq questions should:

> Be marked as community wiki. Any FAQ
>   post not yet community wiki should be
>   made into a community wiki.

And yet a lot of FAQs aren't: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+wiki%3A0

This includes one by [Jeff Atwood ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) and one by [Troggy ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30475/official-stance-on-facebook-questions-on-su).

A moderator should go through them and mark all of them as CW.

Comment: Cheaters! Ban Jeff and Troggy!

Comment: "A moderator should". A moderator will do whatever he wills to do. You are in no place to say what a moderator "should" do. A moderator might even suspend your account for your outrageous attitude.

Comment: @Gnoupi: are you being sarcastic?

Comment: if he answers *No*, how can you be sure that the no isn't sarcastic?

Comment: @perbert: Is today Opposite Day? I never can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they need to be CW. If somone writes a good FAQ entry, why shouldn't they get meta rep for it? That also prevents total newbies from editing the FAQ. I suspect the rule predates meta - you shouldn't earn SO (or SF, SU) rep from editing FAQ entries for those sites.

Answer (score 1):

Flag them for moderator attention and if they think they need to be converted, they'll move them over.

Comment: I can't flag them all, and I also wanted to see the community's opinion on this. For example I wanted to see if I received answers such as "no, I don't agree, they don't have to be CW. The FAQ index should be updated"