# Better reputation history report

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I've been using StackOverflow for over a year now and I still don't know how to fully interpret the reputation history graphs.  Can we get more help on what is being displayed and probably more information about why we got upvoted, downvoted, and for what message, comments, etc?

Comment: See: [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation for Meta

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation for Stack Overflow

Basic format is as follows:

**VT PN (rep)**

Where:
VT = Vote type - 1 = Accept, 2 = Upvoted, 3 = Downvote(d) (depends on number in (rep))
PN = Post number
(rep) = Rep gained/lost