# What made me lose 4 points in 2 comments here?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

[Weird event behavior in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301/weird-event-behavior-in-ie7/3196171#3196171)

My votes are on 0 - was I voted up and then down?

Comment: Related: [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Comment: That's not a comment, that's an answer. My guess to the down vote is the last sentence. It's kind of unclear and potential false (hard to right a good sentence like that with the word "never").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael says, you got one up and one down on that answer, but you also got one down on your question: [Negative look-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288494), which is why you went -4 totally in the last few days.

If you go into your own user page and go to the reputation tab you can then see that in the last 5 days or so you've only had those two downvotes but no upvotes anywhere.

Comment: +10 - 2 - 2 = +6

Comment: So the next question would be: Why would my question be downvoted? Am I being stalked by someone who hates me? And where are the rest of the rep. Auditing says 1,047, actual says 1,039

Comment: @radp: But it was old questions and the upvotes were older than the downvotes so it looked like -4.

Comment: @mplungjan: I think two downvotes are a few too few to assume that someone is stalking you. I'd assume it's just some people disagreeing (or possibly just one person, but even then I'd say that 2 downvotes != stalking. Your rep will get out of sync until the next re-calc, you can ask for a moderator to re-calc it now if you want, just raise a request on one of your questions/answers.

Comment: Thanks - I was kidding a little. But still weird

Comment: @ho1: oh, good point, I can see that happening.

Comment: @mplunjan: Sorry, if I came across as patronising, I assume everyone on the internet is (at least) a little bit crazy. It might not always be true, but usually it saves a bit of time.

Answer (score 2):

You received one upvote on that answer, and one downvote, for a net reputation gain of (10-2) 8 (as of this writing).

Users with at least 1,000 reputation can click on the vote and see the count of distinct up- and down-votes.

Use the [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) to see where you've gained, and lost, points recently.

Comment: Thanks - still wondering about these votes...