# How can I see today's reputation increases, only and also which increases were blocked by the rep cap

Tags: discussion, reputation

How can I see today's reputation increases/decreases, only. Also, I would like to see which increases were blocked by the rep cap

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/reputation. (Or `whicheverSiteYouCareAbout`/reputation.) The top two answers at the linked post explain how to read the report.

Comment: @Popular, not necessarily.  This one specifically asks for today's info and the other question doesn't mention the Recent Activity page.

Comment: @rchern, `/reputation` breaks activity down by day, and uses square brackets for capped activity. It's an _exact_ dupe.

Comment: @Popular, yes, that way works, but isn't Recent Activity filtered on today just as valid an answer?  A bit easier to get to also.

Comment: @rchern, actually, no, Recent Activity only shows the top five, so it's slightly inferior. The Reputation tab might be just as valid. But it's still an exact dupe.

Comment: @Popular, Only the top 5?  I didn't know that.  That does change things. ):  Sorry.

Comment: @rchern Reputation does show the entire day, though. So if you just move your freehand circle a wee-bit to the right...

Comment: @Grace, edited.  Everything look ok now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of the screen, click the envelope icon to the left of your username to view your Recent Activity.

[image: envelope]

Use the filters to show the data you want, ie, reputation.  (Summary only shows the top 5)

[image: filters]

Your reputation will be shown via the boxes to the left of each item.  The top number is the number of votes and the bottom number is the amount of rep you got.

[image: rep]

If the 2nd number does not exist or is lower than expected, it means it has been rep capped.

#### This is the correct way.

You can also go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to view your reputation audit.  Scroll to the end to see today's data.  (/reputation will work on any of the sites)