# Where did my last reputation points come from?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have used Stack Overflow for more than a month now, but I am still unable to figure out the exact source of my last reputation points. How to find that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the envelope icon next to your username at the top of the page and then select "Today" or the time span you want to get info from.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Jon Skeet's wondrous reputation tracker at [csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check out your [reputation audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) detailed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation).