# Upvote is not increasing rep by 10

Tags: support, reputation, questions, daily-reputation-limit

**

### Its Premature Daily cap Hit

**

[Casting boolean to Boolean in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977830/casting-boolean-to-boolean-in-java/3977855#3977855)

for this question there are 6 upvote for now.and only 46 + points are there,
From my toda's rep score it is clear that I haven't hit the cap yet + Q. is active + I haven't been downvoted there
[image]

Up vote doesn't increments my points But down vote does :(
[image]

For last two days it shows

```
    -- 2010-10-18 rep +180  = 5999      
 2   3958581 (10)
 1   3959088 (15)
 2   3967218 (10)
 2   3967218 (10)
 2   3967218 (10)
 2   3967218 (10)
 2   3967218 (10)
 2   3968734 (10)
 2   3959949 (10)
 2   3959799 (10)
 2   3968734 (10)
 2   3967737 (10)
 2   3968734 (10)
 2   3554153 (10)
 1   3781876 (15)
 1   3958581 (15)
 2   3969800 (10)
 2   3968687 (10)
 2   3971729 (10)
 2   3971597 (10)
 2   3971729 (10)
-- 2010-10-19 rep +225  = 6224      
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3976133 (10)
 2   3976133 (10)
 2   3976322 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3976322 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3975836 (10)
 2   3977855 (10)
 2   3977855 (10)
 2   3977855 (10)
 2   3977855 (10)
 2   3977855 (10)
 2   3977855 (10)
 2   3977855 (10)
 2   3979815 [0]
 3   3979815 [-2]
 2   3980016 [2]
 2   3980016 [0]
 2   3980016 [0]
 2   3980016 [0]
 2   3980016 [0]
 2   3980467 [0]
 1   3980467 [15]
-- 2010-10-20 rep +215  = 6439
```

Further there is no addition in vote for
[Uses of the modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979992/uses-of-the-modulus-operator/3980016#3980016)

**UPDATE:**
Its 0000 hrs IST and its now showing me 215 points , but i am not sure now that is it correct , let me know here

Comment: What does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation say? Everything else is irrelevant and could have to do with caching issues or moon eclipses.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer  , I didn't understand this format.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) is the FAQ for the reputation audit, but to save you time: left number is the vote id number (2 is upvote, 3 is downvote); middle number is the post id number (what post got the activity); third number is how much reputation change happened.

Comment: @Grace Note, @Ladybug Killer I added my log here. from that it conflicts with reality

Comment: Like @Lady mentioned, everything currently happening can simply be cacheing issues or other kinds of unusualities. Flag a post of yours for moderator attention and request a reputation recalculation - after that happens, your reputation will match the correct value as shown in the reputation audit. When that happens, check your envelope report to see if it is still displaying wonky numbers.

Comment: @Grace Thanks I did that lets see what happens

Comment: @Grace btw how will i come to know the response of moderatod about flagged question

Comment: You'll know if a moderator recalculated your reputation because it will match the number at the end of your report instead of being different (since it is off by almost 100, this will be very noticeable). Some moderators will also post a comment or send you an email stating they ran the recalc, what your reputation was prior, and what it ended up as.

Comment: @Grace Note Thanks, BTW what is exact daily rep limit . I guess its 215, yesterday it too happen with me i stopped @ 213 only.

Comment: The reputation limit is 200. However, this only affects reputation gain from upvotes. Getting over 200 reputation is a result of the bonuses for accepted answers (the +2 and +15), and the winnings of bounties.

Comment: @Grace Thanks :), but in our case its only 176, so its totally premature :p

Comment: Looks like @Grace handled this gracious, so there is nothing left for me to explain :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at a PC at the moment, so I can't really see the full logs; however, a recalc shows that the shown rep had drifted from the *real* rep by about 100 - most likely due to points from a question that was later deleted.

Let me know if the numbers still don't make sense.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for your answer, but numbers are still confusing . It stopped @ 176 and at 1200 IST it drifted to 215 . I'll expect more  clarification. I have also updated final log for rep

Comment: Marc or @mmyers, can either of you spot to see if org.life.java has a recently deleted answer with 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes? That would amount to 24 reputation, which would have been sufficient to bring 176 to 200 and treat it as if the reputation cap was hit.

Comment: @Grace @Marc ,last night @ 0000 hrs it was 6439 not it is 6422 only 1 downvote is there. I really don't understand what is going on !

Comment: @org - the extra -15 is simply: someone unaccepted an answer; perhaps it turned out that (after inspection) another answer was preferable / more complete.

Comment: @Marc That is true :) But still question is un answered, about the scenario of yesterday

Comment: @Marc The same thing happened today @179 score

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on the `Today` link again, it has a weird default.

Comment: did it 3-4 times

Comment: Hmm. I got nothing: http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=260990&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showzero=true&showflair=true

Comment: Probably a deleted post, you will get the rep if you ask for a recalc. try http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977830/casting-boolean-to-boolean-in-java/3977855#3977855  This is the link to post and it hasn't been deleted

Comment: @Jeff what is going on ? Every time you resolve such issues , so notifying you :)

Comment: The screenshot shows that the timestamp for "Today" is correct, it's going from 00:00:00Z to 23:59:59Z. The default isn't an issue here.

Comment: @Grace Note  then what can be ?

Comment: @org, saying "@Jeff" here won't do anything since Jeff hasn't participated anywhere in this conversation yet.

Comment: @popular oh.. I thought system will notify him any how.

Comment: @org: [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/54262)

Comment: (Actually, a "global" comment reply would be kind of cool, something like @@Jeff or @@Marc to get a moderator's attention. I bet it'd drive them crazy after a while, though. Plus, flags sort of already do that, though they're not specific.)

Comment: I'll recalc... :)

Comment: See, Marc's watching....