# How do I know which answer was up voted?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes, timestamps

If I have answered dozens of questions in the last day, and I see my reputation go up, how do I know which answer was up voted?

In activity I see **Answered**, **Commented**, **Accepted**, but no indication of an up or down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bar on the top of every page, click on the envelope before your name, then on the "reputation" tab, then on "today".

Comment: The envelope by my name was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: You can also check your rep report by visiting `stackoverflow.com/reputation`, but it's a bit cryptic (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005) for an explanation).

Comment: Nice - it's in plain text, now I have proof! ;)