# Isn't it strange to migrate a question and then immediately close it?

Tags: discussion

This happend to the question [What caused Skype to go down?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215544/what-caused-skype-to-go-down)

Comment: The problem is: there's no feedback for bad migrations. When I think a migration vote is bad, I try to comment, hoping the voter [sees that](http://i.imgur.com/eWsz8.png). But that's about all there is one can do? Though in [All my carrots are gone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72942/all-my-carrots-are-gone/72946#72946), which was erroneously flagged as spam by 6 people, Kop suggested *"Can you maybe contact the users who flagged his answer as spam telling them to be more careful?"* But I'm not sure anyone else but the team can see who voted or flagged?

Comment: (Oh, of course everybody can see who voted, but one cannot be sure all voted with the same reason.)

Comment: @Arjan, when you doubt that the migration was OK, why don't you formulate it as an alternative answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a network infrastructure related question, it was migrated from SO to SF.  Because it was not really an answerable, on-topic question, it was closed.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: I admit that the question as formulated isn't answerable, but no one tried to edit the question. And I think the a lot of people want to know why Skype failed (and implicit if it could happen again). For my personal perception the close was pronounced too quick.

Comment: @bernd_k: Lot of people *want* to know, and few *know* - I'd suspect those few work for Skype, trying to restore the connectivity instead of discussing it on SF. Also, the SF question did result in a link to Skype's own explanation - does it matter that it was a comment instead of answer?

Comment: @bernd_k: I completely agree that a lot of people (myself included) want to know why Skype failed.  I also want to know why the Windows API seems to have been written by aliens, and why there isn't a decent MS Paint-like tool for Ubuntu.  However, I wouldn't ask any of these questions on any SE site.  Maybe these are better topics for chat.  How would you have edited the question to make it appropriate?  As for the speed of the close, if people on the migrated-to site like the question, they should be able to vote to reopen.

Comment: I doubt the migration was okay, unless the Server Fault FAQ needs updating? It now says: *Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. If you are in charge of servers / networks / many desktop PCs (other than your own) then you're in the right place to ask your question! Well, as long as the question is about your servers, your networks, or desktops you support, anyway.* I think this should have been closed as off topic on SO.

Comment: @Piskvor the mentioned link explains why the service is unavailable, but not why the Skype Clients chrashed repeatedly