# JavaScript helper for *stackoverflow.com/reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation-audit, userscript

After finding and reading [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005) I thought it would be a good idea to write some JavaScript that makes the response from https://stackoverflow.com/reputation a little bit more readable and useful.

Here's what I came up with for Opera's UserJS:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include http://*stackoverflow.com/reputation
// ==/UserScript==

// add useful info to the reputation output
window.opera.addEventListener("AfterEvent.DOMContentLoaded",
    function(e)
    {
        var html, pre, host;

        if (e.event.eventPhase != Event.CAPTURING_PHASE) return;

        pre = e.event.target.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
        html = pre.innerHTML;
        host = e.event.target.location.host;

        // link the question/post id
        html = html.replace(/(\d{5,})/g, "<a href=\"http://" + host + "/questions/$1\">$1</a>");

        // explain the various status codes
        html = html.replace(/^(\s*1\s+.*$)/gm, "$1   accepted answer (to or from you)");
        html = html.replace(/^(\s*2\s+.*$)/gm, "$1   upvote (to you)");
        html = html.replace(/^(\s*3\s+.*$)/gm, "$1   downvote (to or from you)");
        html = html.replace(/^(\s*4\s+.*$)/gm, "$1   penalty for post flagged as offensive");
        html = html.replace(/^(\s*8\s+.*$)/gm, "$1   bounty grant (from you)");
        html = html.replace(/^(\s*9\s+.*$)/gm, "$1   bounty award (to you)");
        html = html.replace(/^(\s*12\s+.*$)/gm, "$1   penalty for post flagged as spam");

        // append further links to reputations
        e.event.target.body.innerHTML +=
            "<hr>more reputation:<br>" +
            "<a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/reputation\">https://stackoverflow.com/reputation</a><br>" +
            "<a href=\"http://cooking.stackexchange.com/reputation\">http://cooking.stackexchange.com/reputation</a><br>" +
            "<a href=\"http://serverfault.com/reputation\">http://serverfault.com/reputation</a><br>" +
            "<a href=\"http://gaming.stackexchange.com/reputation\">http://gaming.stackexchange.com/reputation</a><br>" +
            "<a href=\"http://superuser.com/reputation\">http://superuser.com/reputation</a><br>" +
            "<a href=\"http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation\">http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation</a><br>";

        pre.innerHTML = html;
    }, false);
```

Could anyone convert this to other browsers in case they support some client-side JavaScript?

*I assume this is more of a wiki-entry than a question, but I can't create a wiki-question.*

Comment: This script makes certain naive assumptions, especially the regex used to match posts: `/(\d{5,})/g`, which will match *any* number in the page that has 5 or more digits. Newer SE sites have post ids starting with 1, and 10k users have reputation more than 5 digits.

Comment: actually, I think this might be a better fit on http://stackapps.com than here, honestly

Comment: @JeffAtwood I thought StackApps is only for scripts that actually uses the API? Because this one, as far as I can tell, doesn't.

Comment: @yij true, I guess there's no good place for greasemonkey stuff other than here then

Comment: Starting a bounty to award it to YiJiang's answer. That is such great work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've rewritten the script so that it works on Firefox, Chrome and Opera. It now lists *all* sites in the Stack Exchange network, by using the API to retrieve the list of sites. I've also updated the regex to avoid the problem I mentioned in the comments.

> #### [Stack Exchange Reputation Audit Helper](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/94727)
>
> **[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/94727.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/94727)**

**Edit:** I've updated the parser to infer from the amount of rep changed the type of accepted answer and downvote that was given.

Comment: Whow, I didn't know there were that many related sites. Anyway, thanks for your work. There isn't really much left from my code ;).

Comment: Just FYI, you may want to add askubuntu to the include list

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Added, together with a few others I missed. Thanks!