# I would like to see for what I was rewarded reputation points

Tags: feature-request, reputation

When viewing my reputation history I would love to know why I was awarded that particular amount. Was it for answering the question, up votes, etc.?

Maybe a tool tip when you mouse over the amount awarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about the reputation audit `/reputation` page? [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005) on the reputation audit FAQ details the different vote types that you see on that page.

> - 1 = accepted answer (to or from you)
> - 2 = upvote (to you)
> - 3 = downvote (to or from you)
> - 4 = penalty for post flagged as offensive
> - 9 = bounty award (to you)
> - 8 = bounty grant (from you)
> - 12 = penalty for post flagged as spam

Alternatively, you can grab the userscript I created [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75081/javascript-helper-for-stackoverflow-com-reputation), which adds the vote type description behind each vote.

Comment: Yep, didn't know it existed.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Also clicking on the envelope next to your profile name at the top.  Has some good reputation details about recent rep.

Comment: Wow...and I thought it had to do with email notifications.  I can't believe I've never clicked that!  Thanks!