# What does VoteTypeId 15 mean?

Tags: support, data-dump, voting

In the January 2011 data dump, a VoteTypeId value of 15 started showing up in votes.xml, but the readme.txt file only documents VoteTypeId values up to 13.  What kind of vote has VoteTypeId="15"?

Comment: Care to compare that `readme.txt` to the list at [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005) and enhance that list, if applicable? (That list currently only shows 1-4, 8-9 and 12.) Thanks!

Comment: They've all got a CreationDate of midnight, starting from 20th Dec, if that helps? Autogenerated for something?

Comment: @Arjan I think that list already has all the vote types relevant to reputation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are flags that record when a moderator reviews a post or comment. Essentially a "response" to VoteTypeId = 13 (InformModerator), which is not included in the data dump.

I assume they are part of the new system that tracks how frequently flags for mod attention are acted upon, which is why the data only goes back 4 weeks or so (as opposed to only keeping a 4 week history). As it sits, that data doesn't really say much, and may be stripped from subsequent dumps.

I've updated the [data dump schema docs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) to reflect this new type. I've [fixed up](http://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=0cde0a9fc3fa7cde15cb6effc5c9f070a345dc94) the Data Explorer VoteTypes table as well, which will show up next month when the data is updated.