# Is the “time to live” of non-answers decreasing?

Tags: discussion, flags, statistics

Given all the flagging of non-answers that is going on, does anyone have any stats on the effectivenesss of our efforts?

Comment: I kill about 200 of these per day on SO.  So yes, I think it's helping.

Comment: If the [moderator review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75314/what-does-votetypeid-15-mean/75419#75419) votes are retained in the next iterations of the data dump, you can find out using SEDE.

Comment: @Jon, how could I tell from these if it is a few posts being flag by lots of people or lots of posts being flagged by one person each.

Comment: You can't -- voting source information is anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

I am **now** finding that when I go to https://stackoverflow.com/review I now more often than not I see nothing that need flagging.    I used to see 2 or 3 items to flag each time I looked.

Therefore:

- Other people are flagging and the bad posts are being deleted quickly.
- Or there are less bad posts to start with. (Unlikely)
- Or the review page is no longer working to find bad posts

Comment: There's still plenty of older ones though, if you change the period to `Year` or `All` instead of the default `Day` you'll probably see more.

Comment: @ho1, yes but at least very few new ones are now living for now