# Reputation reset to pre-yesterday state

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation

I opened my SO account page this morning and noticed that I lost about 200 reputation that I gained the day before. I visually remember some of the numbers and I see that some of them got decremented by one (no downvotes though). Is this a known issue? Did anyone else notice anything similar?

Comment: No loss for me.

Comment: [Check your reputation audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) by going to [/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation). Check for yesterday's activity to see if it's all still there. Alternatively, look to see if there's any big minuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your post a bit for clarity, but I couldn't quite parse "visually remember." Did you just mean that you remember what it looked like the other day?

If so, this sounds like a case of serial upvoting. Sometimes, someone will like one of your answers a little more than usual for some reason, and go to your profile to find other posts of yours to cast upvotes on. People who do this are usually trying to be nice, but they end up triggering a script that looks for sockpuppets and other reputation cheaters. The script ends up removing all the votes and rep involved, even if you're not at fault and didn't know it was happening.

Comment: I meant that I remembered 3-2-3-... vote sequence visually on my list.  And it became 2-1-2-...  I remember that I got about 200 points that put me over 2k and I got a new privilege.  Now I'm back to where I was before that (under 2k).  So I'm not delusional here ;)  But this script thing makes sense, only I have no idea who would vote me up so much.  I didn't do anything that good lately ;)  I cannot see those votes being cast or taken back in the audit though.

Comment: Man, I messed up the grammar so bad (checked the edit history).  Thanks for correcting all that.  It was early and I was still asleep I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is by-design when the voting fraud detection triggers on your account a recalc is performed.  However, as [the new reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) roll out you'll see a "voting fraud reversal" entry in your reputation tab so you know exactly what happened in this case...so we're being much more informative than before on this.