# I would like to see a "balance sheet"/transaction list of rep points

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

I go through periods of answering a LOT of questions at the same time on StackOverflow.  I'll see my points go up (woot!), but I sometimes don't know why, or even which question the activity was on that earned the points.

The Activity page shows when I did things, but not what I earned from them.  The Reputation chart shows what I've earned points for recently, but not when, so I don't know which one changed to give me the new points, unless I memorize it/print it out and diff it each time I look at it.  And the graph on the reputation pace simply does not work if you try to narrow the range to find out what changed in the past day or two (if I change the range from one month to 2011/02/25 - 2011/02/27 neither the graph or the list of points change).

What I would love to see is like a bank statement: A chart with date (and ideally time), the question, the points earned (and ideally why), and the new balance.  Obviously the database has the data, but there's no way to currently see that.

If there's a way to find this out now without memorizing the current state of every question you've answered/commented on between visits, please let me know.  I would even settle for a way to sort the reputation page on reverse chronological instead of descending points earned.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stackoverflow.com/reputation while logged in? (that works for the rest of the Stack Exchange sites as well).

Comment: uhh.. SWEET!  That's almost exactly what I was looking for!  Is that documented somewhere?  If not, how did you find it?  And why didn't you list that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Being a web page it would be nice if the question IDs where links to the question, but that's easy enough to do myself.  Thank you Tim, and thank you Michael for the link to the previous question which shows how to read it.

Comment: There's a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/94727) that makes the IDs links. I don't think `/reputation` is linked anywhere, but it's pretty well known amongst regulars