# Why does the report of my reputation contain days when my rep did not change?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-audit

Here is the report of my reputation:

> total votes: 26
>   -- bonuses   (100)
>   -- 2009-06-24 rep 0     = 101
>   -- 2009-06-25 rep 0     = 101
>   -- 2009-07-09 rep 0     = 101
>    2      4575 (10)
>    2      4575 (10)
>    2      4575 (10)
>    2      4575 (10)
>    2      4575 (10)
>   **-- 2009-07-12 rep +50   = 151**
>   -- 2009-07-17 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2009-07-28 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2009-07-30 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2009-08-01 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2009-08-20 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2010-09-29 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2010-11-09 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2010-12-29 rep 0     = 151
>   -- 2011-03-01 rep 0     = 151
>    2      4575 (10)
>    2     82132 (10)
>    2     82132 (10)
>   **-- 2011-03-08 rep +30   = 181**
>
> ** rep this week (3/6/2011 - 3/12/2011): 30
>   ** rep this month (3/1/2011 - 3/31/2011): 30
>   ** rep this quarter (1/1/2011 - 3/31/2011): 30
>   ** rep this year (1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011): 30
>   ** total rep 181 :)
>
> days represented 13

So far I have received 8 up-votes on 2 days: 5 on 2009-07-12 and 3 on 2011-03-08. My questions are:

- Why does the first line show "total votes: 26"? I have received only 8.
- Why does the last line show "days represented 13"? I have received reps on 2 days only.
- What happened e.g. on 2009-06-24? Why is that day represented? I did not receive any reps that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It contains all days on which you have visited/logged into the site.

> - Why does the first line show "total votes: 26"? I have received only 8.

Not sure what this means. Just guessing, it is number of votes including the Community wiki votes. Since community wiki votes do not count to your rep, your rep will still be 181 from 8 votes on your questions.

> - Why does the last line show "days represented 13"? I have received reps on 2 days only.

13 is the number of days you have visited/logged into the site

> - What happened e.g. on 2009-06-24? Why is that day represented? I did not receive any reps that day.

This day you registered to this site for the first time. You did get a bonus of 100 rep since your rep on SO is more than 200.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag Thank you for your answer! 1. I have 38 community-wiki up-votes, thus if your guess were right then total votes would show 8+38=46 instead of 26. 2. What does number of days I have visited/logged into the site have to do with reputation? Why are those days represented in a reputation report?

Comment: @Bill - Actually your community wiki question was migrated from stackoverflow. So it can be possible that around 20 votes were already available when question was still on SO. After migration it got some more votes. So META will count only votes added in meta. Also /reputation page is for you to go through your details for all days logged in and rep at that point of time. Its cumulative detailed sheet which I think is good ;)

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag It is very likely that your first assumption is right: my answers to the community wiki question could get 20 up-votes on SO and 18 up-votes on meta. This explains why the report speaks about 26 votes. But your second assumption might be wrong: 13 days are represented because I got votes on 13 days: on 2 days I got votes for non-CW questions and on 11 days I got votes for a CW question. Are you sure that the reputation page contains information about logging in?

Comment: @Bill - Yes. I am pretty sure about it based on my observation. Its kind of days you visited excluding today. Guess, only some developer or moderator of site can answer this with conviction. ;)

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag We can try this out: I am going to log into / visit the site in the following days and we will see whether those days will be represented in the rep log or not.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag On each of the past few days I logged out then logged in but the report of my reputation did not change. The last day represented is 2011-03-11. Nonetheless, thank you for helping me clarify the meaning of entries of rep report.