# How can I find out how often I hit the daily reputation cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Is there a way to get the count how much I hit the reputation cap without opening my recent reputation changes and counting the days by hand?

Comment: See also [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: the shortest working answer i ever accepted :-) Thanks!