# What are the different types of rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-audit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I've noticed on the reputation audit that there seems to be a number of different types of rep:

- 1: accepting an answer (2 for the acceptor, 15 for the acceptee)
- 2: upvote (5 for a question, 10 for an answer)
- 3: downvote (-1 for the downvoter, -2 for the downvotee)
- 9: bounty
- 16: accepted tag wiki edit (2)

Note that I'm *not* asking for answers from the FAQ -- I already know how rep works. I'm wondering what the different values from the first column of the reputation audit mean.

Is there a comprehensive list somewhere? I'm curious how many different types there are and how many points each is worth.

Comment: See [the FAQ for the reputation audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005), then, which lists all of the appropriate values. In the future, please don't rollback a "Possible Duplicate" heading until your question get reopened, though.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't want a link to the *wrong* duplicate at the top of my post.