# I want to know all SO's vote types, Who can provide it for me?

Tags: support, voting, help

I feel the design of SO's vote types is very clever and smart, in [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/), Jeff showed us some vote types, but only part of them.

I want to know all vote types, May be it will help me to design other sites.

Who can provide it for me?

Comment: Why are you saying it doesn't list all the vote types?

Comment: Because of the vote types' number:1,2,3,4,9,8,12,16. and he listed the types which related to reputation. I guess it must have other types that related to Badges or others.

Comment: Notice: I won't copy SO, Just feel the design very compact, So, please don't vote down to me.

Comment: A badge is not going to give you reputation. Think of all the ways you can earn reputation. And then compare against the list.

Comment: Favorite = 5, but I don't know the others.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're not insinuating why you care. "I'm not gonna copy SO" and "I feel the design is very clever" ... what _is_ your intent here?

Comment: Do you think someone have the ability to copy SO?

Comment: @Roy yes, see the OSQA project for starters. It's not hard to copy the intent of SO, what's hard is to attract away all of the actual users that make SO great. You may also be interested in [ReactOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReactOS)

Comment: OSQA will never catch up with SO, I think. Innovative product is much better than copycat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com):

> Id Name
>
> ---
>
> 1  AcceptedByOriginator
>
> 2  UpMod
>
> 3  DownMod
>
> 4  Offensive
>
> 5  Favorite
>
> 6  Close
>
> 7  Reopen
>
> 8  BountyStart
>
> 9  BountyClose
>
> 10 Deletion
>
> 11 Undeletion
>
> 12 Spam
>
> 13 InformModerator
>
> 15 ModeratorReview
>
> 16 PendingEditRepBonus