# Does down-voting cause me to lose extra points?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I had a reputation of 788 on Stack Overflow; I down-voted a post because it was not answering the question, and abruptly my reputation went to 785.  The only reputation activity on my account for today was the -2 on the down-vote. Why did I lose 3 points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the -1 you got from giving the downvote, you received a downvote yourself on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324822/php-session-lost-on-subdomain/7324858#7324858).

Comment: is that not recorded in the rep tracker?

Comment: @Jeremy: I can see the -2 on [your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/610217/jeremy?tab=reputation). You should be able to see the -1 from the downvote you gave.

Comment: How odd.  I see a +10 for someone upvoting me and a -2 for my downvote, and nothing else.

Comment: @Jeremy: The answer you downvoted is now deleted, so the -1 doesn't show up any more. To get your 1 Rep back, you can trigger a [Rep recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004/52738).

Comment: @gnostradamus It's no fun when you tell us what _has happened_ ;)