# Reputation URL - intentional, hidden feature, or bug?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

I went to this URL expecting an explanation of reptuation scores on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

I was surprised to find a completely plain-text dump of some sort of voting numbers.  I didn't linger long enough to actually interpret any of the data.

Same is true on the main site: http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation

Is this deliberate, or is this the man behind the curtain peeking out?

Comment: Short answer: it's meant to be like that.