# Reputation differs depending on which site I look at it from

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

Well I have just noticed something odd. I've waited for a couple of days, but it hasn't changed. On my Stack Overflow account I have (at the time of posting) 556 rep. If I go to my account on Game Development I find that it says I only have 541. When I look at my rep on Game Development I have 406, but from Stack Overflow it says I have 421. Which should I believe? Is this normal?

Comment: That's funny--they're both differences of 15. Something seems fishy. For what it's worth I'm getting the same error on your profiles.

Comment: @Purmou well at least it's not a cache problem like just about every other glitch I've found. I'd like to know how to fix it, or at least which one is right though

Comment: Have you tried a rep recalc on either site? (That is, go to `stackoverflow.com/reputation` and then `gamedev.stackexchange.com/reputation` and use the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button at the bottom.)

Comment: I can reproduce this here on meta, too. Your profile's summary tab says you have 541 rep on SO and 421 on GameDev, whereas the Accounts tab says 556 for SO and 406 for GameDev.

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh, if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it so everyone can find this solution. Actually I just noticed that only SO worked but the glitch still happens on gamedev

Comment: @AnnaLear isn't there daily job doing reputation recalc? Or even weekly?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: There may be, but I recently recalculated my rep and it deducted 12 points. I actually took the time and did the math myself and it turned out to be right. There are some interesting things going on with rep.

Comment: @Purmou I also saw here on Meta user with no activity at all whatsoever but with 21 reputation, as if he got upvotes on deleted question or answer - but assumed this will at some point get recalculated and he'll have the proper 1 rep. Hard to believe just manual recalc will "work" as 99.99999% of the users are not even aware of this. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yeah...I also just recalculated my rep here on meta and it went from 871 to 877. How do these miscounts even come about?

Comment: @Purmou usually if the reputation is going down, it means upvotes you got were lost due to deleted posts. If the rep is going up it means answers you downvoted got deleted - from what I see, deleting a post won't recalculate the reputation of those voting for it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, there's not. The recalc is performed in some cases (like when a suspension expires or accounts are merged) but otherwise it has to be triggered manually.

Comment: @AnnaLear so [this user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174286/kencs) will have 21 reputation for good or until he'll perform manual recalc?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes. Or until he gets suspended or a moderator/dev does the recalc for him.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks.. wasn't sure about all this until now. Is there a faq page about this subject?

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, and I have the badge to prove I checked ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know if there's a single FAQ page, but it's kind of covered between [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation).

Comment: @AnnaLear I think rep should be recalculated regularly like once a week or something so that at least you know that if you wait long enough it will be correct.