# Reputation loss

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

In my SO account I had 1144 reputation yesterday But when I check today it was 1092 so what was the reason for that? (I have checked there was no unaccepted and down votes) Is it bug? I lost 22 reputations...

Comment: I think you lost 52... just saying ;)

Comment: @Lix It was 22 but type mistake, 1114 my previous...

Comment: *Twenty two points???*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the history log of your profile it looks like an automated reputation recalculation took place.

Over time, your displayed rep can begin to differ from the real number due to deleted questions, answers, and users.

SO does a recalc from time to time to sync those numbers back up. (You can see the real number at any time.  [Check out this other meta post for info on that.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation))

That said, there will be some larger changes taking place that will make this conversation obsolete.  [Check out the banner that is running for more info on that.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)

Comment: Hooray for that. The sooner the better.

Comment: How do you know if your rep just got recalculated?