# How can I find the reason of the reputation lost?

Tags: support, reputation

The reputation I gained in a specific day passed from 115 to 90, as shown the next day. In the summary, I haven't found anything that could explain why the reputation was decreased.

How can I find the reason of the reputation lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [the reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869233/sarooptrivedi?tab=reputation)

Click the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom

[image]

You should see an account of wherever you lost rep due to deleted posts, etc (i.e, non-public stuff).

If it still doesn't add up, go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, scroll down, and select "Trigger Reputation Recalc". This isn't supposed to be needed now, but it doesn't hurt to try :)

Comment: Care to copy this to the FAQ at [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) (Earlier I've flagged to merge, but no cigar.)

Comment: @Arjan: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135613/178438