# Reputation section has wrong link

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, help-center

On [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/why-register) when you click on `reputation` you get a text only version of the rep page.

Is it supposed to be like this? Because I don't think that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) can help new users understand what reputation is.

Comment: Yeah, not great. It's the (obsolete?) reputation audit page: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation

Comment: _Probably_ because that help-page is written for non-logged-in users, but even that doesn't make any sense does it? Maybe it's a static page? Hmmm ... needs to point to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/{id}/{username}?tab=reputation` doesn't it?

Comment: (@Bart Not entirely obsolete. It's still possible for your reputation to get out-of-sync in some rare cases. I've had to trigger a manual recalc recently.)

Comment: @jcolebrand Just tested : Non-logged users will get the `This page requires more privilege...` page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a mistake; it now links to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-reputation which actually tells you what reputation is. :)

Comment: Yeah thanks :)! Makes more sense. Also, that was fast.