# Does upvote rollback when question is removed from community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki, community-data

I added one of my answer to community wiki by mistake. And asked moderator to remove it.

If a moderator removes CW, is the reputation earned from upvotes while the answer was CW preserved, or is it lost?

Comment: The upvotes are not rolled back, but I'm not sure if you get credit for the rep earned while the answer was CW.

Comment: the first question comes to mind... How many up votes?

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head. Link to the post?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Can't get you?

Comment: @AnnaLear Are you asking for link of the post?

Comment: Why are you worry about, few 10s points, you should take SO as learning sharing of your knowledge, points wont help you. I know many SO friends with few thousand reps but more knowledge than me :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes you are absolutely right. But as question is raised in my mind, it's human tendency to search for an answer :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - I believe the post in question is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546170/jquery-selectors-what-is-wrong-with-my-code/17546274#17546274 . I rolled back the CW status on it earlier today. Looks like it's as Robert says.

Comment: @BradLarson Heh, I was partially responding to Robert. I seem to have left eloquence and clarity at home today, though. The upvotes are definitely not rolled back (not a surprise there - that'd be pretty weird behaviour if we undid the votes), but the rep will be awarded as if the post was never wiki'd.

Answer (score 4):

After referring to FAQ section of meta.stackoverflow.com, I got my answer to this question.

Reputation upvotes are rollback. Answer is found over [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Alternatively you can also "Recalc Reputation" of stackoverflow using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

FAQ section is awesome :)

Comment: Meta is wonderful too, to know how things works and to learn a trick or two :)