# Downvote recorded with no rep record

Tags: support, reputation, voting, summary

I'm well versed with the Stack Exchange voting system, but **I don't understand why this downvote, which had a record of -2 earlier today now has not rep count**. I've had a browse on Meta and cannot find the answer to this. For [a link](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/87/skippy?tab=reputation) to see this live.

[image]

It also showed up with a total of 3 rep (the first upvote and the down vote).
[image]

Comment: Account: http://pets.stackexchange.com/users/87/skippy?tab=reputation Question: [Whether and how to minimise physical activity of female dog immediately following desexing operation?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/90)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it won't take your rep because you are currently at 1...

Comment: @Bart it had it there earlier, it disappeared, and I thought maybe the user had been removed??

Comment: @Bart: I see -2s on another temp-suspended account. And from the votes on days previous this account would be well above 1 if it wasn't temp-suspended.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is not usual is it?? it's the sort of thing that happens when you go over the 200 limit

Comment: @Skippy: There can be other reasons, I just haven't found the reason for *this* instance yet. Downvotes still count when you go over the rep cap, later upvotes then compensate for it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was meaning if you have a net daily rep gain of ay 300 and then get a downvote, it will appear like the upvotes, with no rep change? I have been complaining about being downvoted and one of the CMs was looking into it.. But the other downvotes don't seem to have changed?? O.O So I dunno.. Just giving you the background.. Tim Post *may* know not sure

Comment: Hmm, okay @MartijnPieters. Weirdness then. I'll give the wheel a spin.

Comment: @Skippy: No, downvotes **will** show as -2 unless the post is a Community Wiki post even when you have hit the reputation cap. I see no evidence that that is the case here.

Comment: @Bart maybe it's the universe, the post didn't deserve a downvote ;)

Comment: Can you try and visit http://pets.stackexchange.com/reputation and click on the 'trigger reputation recalc' button at the bottom?

Comment: @MartijnPieters done  http://pets.stackexchange.com/reputation?recalc=true

Comment: @Skippy: No change, so this was caused by something else. It's up to the developers now, I fear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you pls explaing the numbers in the column for the rep calc..there may be a post on it?

Comment: @Skippy: They are vote type and post id, respectively. 1 is accept, 2 is answer upvote, 3 is a downvote (either you downvoted or someone else downvoted your post), etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah easy, post id was what was confusing me.. I'm reading up about rep recalc, can I do this on my accounts? and how freq?

Comment: @Skippy: you *already* did a recalc. You can do it once a day at most, but should not be needed, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know I just did a recalc LOL I mean on my other SE sites

Comment: Cache. The magic word. My assumption is that your reputation was cached with the value before suspension when you first saw the page, hence you saw the +2. Then at some point something cleared the cache on the server, it realized you actually had 1 rep in the beginning of the day and the display corrected itself. I doubt a dev will bother looking into it deep enough to solve the mystery, so assumptions are all we got. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, it was suspended yesterday and received votes yesterday after suspension.. sorry ;)  And it was the -2 besides the downvote that registered for the daily total and was there that is now missing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a rep record, it's just not reflected in your summary because of the current status of your account. When that status changes, all votes that you've received will be recalculated and your reputation normalized again.

Remember, rep can't go below 1 (ever), and while an account is suspended, it can't go *over* 1. I do realize that the display is inconsistent, but the cause of it is the temporary status of the account, so it's unlikely to be corrected.

You can audit your reputation easily by visiting {site}.stackexchange.com/reputation while logged in, [which gives you a full accounting of the votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/50049) in the system that constitute your reputation score. It can take a little while to get used to the nomenclature in that display, but I think you'll find it easier to parse once you have.

**Edit**

This does appear to be caching, but .. strange. I've seen *posts* not reflected, or scores not reflected, but never a post with a vote type without a score. Looking into it.

Comment: But Mr Post, it was there as -2 and then vanished... is my account part of the bermuda triangle, the victim of an [se] poltergeist, and shouldn't such an urgent and vital issue for the internet be addressed rigorously?? ;)

Comment: @Skippy there are a lot of decaffeinated brands on the market that are _just as tasty_ as the real thing. (I am looking into it, but as it's an artifact of the account status, it's very likely going to be a status-wontfix since it applies to a very narrow group of people).

Comment: I'm accepting this as answer, even though it does not satisfy my quest for enlightenment, as it is always good to learn to accept life in this case [se] on life's terms :)) *I hope people appreciate my humour- it's all tongue in cheek*

Comment: @Skippy The metas ... they've .... _assimilated_ you! Ponies! Ponies! Ponies!

Comment: I need a cigarette and another coffee with my new coffee machine.. I'm failing to understand basic java principles and am frightened of overloading [programmers.se], [codereview.se] and [so] with my questions

Comment: Have a look at my answer... isn't this truly Amazing? *seriously could I get any more boring?* lol

Comment: **BUT** you must remember it had the **-2** and then it vanished!! and I have a terrible karmic debt, so pls don't discount poltergeists