# What are all the IDs on the /reputation page, and what do they mean?

Tags: support, reputation

Here's an excerpt from my https://stackoverflow.com/reputation page:

```
 1  14132869 (2)
 1  14132300 (15)
 3  14138562 (-1)
 2  14138574 (10)
 2  14138574 (10)
 2  14138746 (10)
 2  14140825 (10)
 2  14140825 (10)
 2  14140825 (10)
 2  14140825 (10)
 16 14140805 (2)
```

From what I've gathered so far, the IDs are:

- 1: accepted an answer or have an answer accepted
- 2: upvote
- 3: downvote or downvoted
- 16: got a suggested edit approved

I see a few things missing:

- deleted posts or removed votes - I can't seem to find any
- setting or earning a bounty - I've never done either
- the -100 penalty for getting a post deleted as spam/offensive - obviously never done that

What are the IDs for those? Are there any more I'm missing?

Comment: [Here you go](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/145923/view-all-vote-types). :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Hmm, thanks, but what's a `ModeratorReview` vote? And why don't I see any `Deletion` or `Undeletion` events in my history, even though I'm sure they've happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the ID's of the vote type in the database, as can be seen [in this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/145923/view-all-vote-types):

[image]

As you see, the -100 should be there with ID of 4 (offensive) or 12 (spam).

There are more details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation), and as far as I could see and understand removed posts simply do not show in the reputation audit page.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but what's a `ModeratorReview` vote? And why don't I see any `Deletion` or `Undeletion` events in my history, even though I'm sure they've happened? And what's the difference between `BountyStart` and `BountyClose`? And why is there no 13 or 14?

Comment: See my edit, also found a proper dupe.