# How can I see reputation changes for a particular date range in stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, down-votes, up-votes

Is there any option available for finding the reputation changes for a particular period of time? For example, we've got many up votes and a couple of down votes too for that period. So how do we see all those changes?

Comment: Have you looked at your Profile and clicked on Reputation? If yes, what else is it that you need?

Comment: @PompousQWoodger Specific range I meant. like from date to To date?

Comment: Paper and pencil or search for `Data Explorer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your profile has this information. (Step 0: go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834030).) Add up the count for each day.

[image: rep graph]

Also, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834030/jenson-m-john?tab=reputation&sort=graph) does steps 1 and 2 for you.

---

Another method (less visually pleasing IMO; requires same amount of work) is to [**audit your reputation**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/228314). To view all reputation changes, visit

```
http://sitename.com/reputation
```

(i.e. [stackoverflow.com/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)).