# What does "total votes" mean in the /reputation page?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, voting, reputation-audit

When I enter in https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I get:

```
total votes: 13612
../..
** total rep 77748 :)
```

When I do the same in https://askubuntu.com/reputation I get:

```
total votes: 146
../..
** total rep 715 :)
```

A reputation of 77K comes from 7.8K votes, the most (because reputation comes quite often from accepted answers). Similarly, 715 rep is around 70 votes.

So I wonder: what does this "total votes" refer to? Adding the votes that I casted to the sum does not become this number, neither.

Comment: I've added the `bug` tag, as the OP still seems to be correct: the value reported in "total votes" seems to have no rational explanation. See his/her last comment here [What does "total votes" mean in the /reputation page?](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/862476).

Comment: @JosephQuinsey this can't really be a bug until we know for sure what this number **should** be. The given answer isn't official, and isn't full.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) describing how to audit your reputation, there are 8 different 'votes' counted in the list:

- accepted answer (to or from you)
- upvote (to you)
- downvote (to or from you)
- penalty for post flagged as offensive
- bounty grant (from you)
- bounty award (to you)
- penalty for post flagged as spam
- edit suggestion approved

So in fact it aren't just votes, it is anything that influences your reputation.

Comment: Mmm I still miss numbers. I counted the lines of /reputation in [SO] that do not start with "--" (dates) and I see 8416. If I add my almost 6000 votes cast, the number looks quite similar to the "total votes". So maybe it is this: upvotes, downvotes, accepts received + votes cast. Edit: but no, in Ask Ubuntu this rule doesn't match.

Comment: Maybe it includes your downvotes too since they influence your score too.

Comment: Looks like own upvotes also counted, even though they do not affect reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, it still doesn't explain all the total votes. If you download your /reputation in a file, say `rep` and run this little script: `awk 'NR==1; $1 == 1 || $1 == 2 || $1 == 3 || $1 == 4 || $1 == 8 || $1 == 9 || $1 == 12 || $1 == 16 {s++} END {print "counted votes:", s}' rep` you are likely to get different values. To me, `total votes: 13628` whereas the sum is `7544`.