# How can I check my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm fairly new to this site, I've used it a lot for research, but never actually created an account until just recently, and so far, it doesn't seem to be very self-explanatory. I wanted to check my reputation, but it's not labelled anywhere on my profile, I was thinking it might be the little coin with the number next to it at the top of the page, but I just wanted to make sure. Is this correct? And if not, how can I check my reputation?

Edit: Also, do you have a separate reputation for each community?

Comment: see also: [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Comment: Doesn't look like it, he's asking a question about reputation, he's already found it, I want to know how to find it in the first place.

Comment: Though, looks like there's a reputation tab, I checked it out, looks like reputation IS separate for each community, correct?

Comment: Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). See where the arrow points in the section called "You earn reputation when people vote on your posts"?

Comment: Thanks! (Is it normal to thank? I know some forum sites consider it spam, but I'm new to this one so I'm not quite sure)