# I didn't get the association bonus at Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, association-bonus

I recently joined a community via Area 51 using my Stack Exchange account. I got 100 reputation points on every other site except Stack Overflow.

I don't know why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Comment: Looks like you [did get the association bonus on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7615140/sakir-sherasiya?tab=reputation) 3 hours ago, as listed in the reputation tab. Is this not what you expected?

Comment: @animuson completed? Was there really a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to your account page you did](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7615140/sakir-sherasiya?tab=reputation)

[image]

The comments caught something I missed - that you actually need associated sites to get the bonus, and you had none till today. Nonetheless, at this point, you have the bonus you earned on all the sites you are on, including SO

Comment: But it doesn't count in reputation.

Comment: @Sakir: What does that mean? It clearly shows your reputation has gone up. You've gained 151 reputation points on SO today.

Comment: No it doesn't make total of my all reputation @ale.

Comment: Of your 141 reputation today, 100 is from that. I didn't really sit down and calculate all your reputation but it looks *about* right

Comment: Do you mean your *network* wide reputation?

Comment: actually, that's a much better question 0_0

Comment: No @ale i don't merge but i get in chess in every site and it will count in reputation

Comment: There's obviously a language barrier here. It might be helpful if you could edit your question to explain what you were expecting to see, and _where_.

Comment: @ale it didn't happen before because the bonus is given only when joining other sites. Until four hours ago, OP had account only on Stack Overflow. Gaining 200 rep on one site never gave the bonus on that single site if there are no other accounts. Everything working as expected, OP  got bonus on SO when joining his first other site.

Comment: @sha: OK, makes sense.

Comment: @Journeyman you can edit the answer to reflect that as well, that's probably the source of confusion for OP.

Comment: I don't understand @Journeyman Geek

Comment: @SakirSherasiya - You need to clarify what your question is exactly.