# When is a date skipped in the reputation audit?

Tags: support, reputation-audit

I noticed that a day is skipped in my [reputation audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/357396) on Hinduism Stack Exchange.

[image: image of reputation audit on Hinduism Stack Exchange]

15th December is missing. However there are days showing I earned zero reputation. Why is 15th December not shown with zero rep?

In which cases are the dates skipped in a reputation audit?

Comment: ok, deleted my comment then.

Comment: Your profile shows no reputation gained december 14th till 16th, but I can't see deleted posts on your profile, you can.

Comment: @Luuklag Yeah, there were no reputation changes for 3 days. But two days are shown with 0 change in reputation and 3rd day is missing. There were no deleted posts on December 15th.

Comment: Were there deleted posts on december 14th and 16th?

Comment: @Luuklag from a quick analysis, days with deleted posts do end up in the list, but I also have 0-rep entries for days without deleted posts.

Comment: @Glorfindel did some research as well. For me 21 november is missing, and 7 and 8 november are shown with a 0 result. I had site activity on all those days. Difference is I only had a comment on 21st november, but did reviews on 7 and 8 november. Perhaps those reviews are stored as votes somewhere?

Comment: It looks like these entries are not only triggered up- and downvotes. I have several larger time frames where I didn't visit any SE site and some days are still listed as 0, but not all though. I didn't get reputation on these days and also didn't vote myself (downvote, which would cost me 2 points). Maybe the missing days are days where were no action at all on any post from you, not even a visit? (which would affect the "people reached" counter)

Comment: @Luuklag No, there are no deleted posts of mine in recent times. Is 21st November your birthday by any chance? :)

Comment: Nope, not by far @NogShine