# Indicate reason and origin of small reputation decrease due to removal of an edited question

Tags: feature-request, reputation, edits, deleted-posts

When one edited (redacted, enhanced) a question and the edit has been accepted, a small reputation (2 points) will be given.

It is not very rare that the question is deleted at a later time, which leads to the loss of these two points.

Can it be made easily traceable for the person concerned where these point losses come from (such as which question he edited was deleted)?

Comment: There's a checkbox to show removed posts at the bottom of the page: see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135613/377214) to our FAQ [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree; it should be in the rep drop down for one simple reason: to dissuade users from submitting pointless edits on posts headed for deletion. It would be like a natural downvote for the edit. These edits fill up the queue (at least on Stack Overflow) and prevent other edits from being submitted. Do the editors learn? Unlikely. It's too hard to notice 2 reputation vanishing (for most users at least), and if you don't visit meta or the Help Center you likely wouldn't even know that this is something that *can* happen.