# Upvote worth +5 instead of +10

Tags: support, reputation

Upon a most recent upvote the notification and reputation increase said/is +5, everywhere else like in the reputation tab it's displaying as +10

Not hit daily limit, not downvoted on any answers today.

Upvoted answer: [Phar archive no read and write permissions with symfony filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015539/phar-archive-no-read-and-write-permissions-with-symfony-filesystem/48015791#48015791)

Can you look into this, not that I care about 5 points, but would like to know why it's only 5?

```
total votes: 11447
 2   5321360 (10)
 ... <snip>     
 2  48015791 (10)
-- 2021-12-14 rep +10   = 43547     

** rep today: 10
** rep this week (2021-12-12 - 2021-12-18): 45
** rep this month (2021-12-01 - 2021-12-31): 165
** rep this quarter (2021-10-01 - 2021-12-31): 592
** rep this year (2021-01-01 - 2021-12-31): 3149
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 43547 :)

days represented 2734
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 2 days
earned 62 reputation from suggested edits
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, Has your reputation gone up by 5 or 10?

Comment: It went up by 5

Comment: what does [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) tell you? see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation

Comment: And where do you see that +5?

Comment: You probably lost 5 reputation on another site. That's combining with the +10 from an upvote there.

Comment: it says 10 but I clearly remember it was 43542 yesterday, so it only went up by 5, and was in the notification at the top of the page, right side nav bar which said +5, then clicked it and it said +10 in the actual drop down and everywhere else

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog ok then which site?

Answer (score 17):

The topbar shows an aggregate reputation change. I can't reconstruct the full picture, but you also had an answer unaccepted yesterday. I'm guessing that the unaccept (-15 points) combined with two upvotes that came after it (+20) gave you the +5 you saw.

I can confidently assure you that the answer upvote was worth 10 points, though.

Comment: thanks for your reply, makes sense. Though is not showing in the reputation tab -15 and from what I've noticed any aggregation would have happened yesterday at some point give or take within the hour, not a day later on next upvote. Ive been on the site most of the day so there wouldn't have been any uncleared changes to the count

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The topbar does not display negative reputation changes, to keep you happy and smiling. The reputation notification is only shown when it combines with subsequent changes to a net positive. That’s why it was delayed until you got two new upvotes.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The top bar notification number/badge does indeed show negative values but in red not green.

Comment: We don't show notifications for only negative changes, but if you have a mix of positive and negative, you'll see whatever they add up to together (if it's above 0). The -15 doesn't show up in the reputation tab because it happened on the same day of the +15 from the accept (within about 5 minutes, actually), so the net result is 0 and rep history doesn't account for it (but I see it in the full breakdown of votes you received). But, like I said, that was just a guess on my part that'd fit what you saw. Topbar values aren't persisted anywhere, so it's hard to say now what actually happened.

Comment: I logged in today had 2 upvotes, compared yesterdays rep and is correct on StackOverflow +20 but the notification said +8 which is not correct so I guess it's linking all sites as got 6 downvotes on this question. I for sure won't be asking for help in future nor reporting confusing odditys