# Why don't I have the "Mortarboard" badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, daily-reputation-badges

May be my question is duplicate but i have confusion.

On March 22 I got 200 reputation:

> [image]

But I didn't get the [Mortarboard badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard). ([Link to my badges list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718224/advait-amin?tab=badges))

I know it takes time to get badge but more than 30 days passed since March 22 and I also know accepting answers for your own questions which brings you +2 points don't count.

Comment: Check the end of this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation). What does it say for **earned at least 200 reputation on**?

Comment: Go to the end of this page : [http://stackoverflow.com/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation). It displays a lot of statistics in RAW format.

Comment: Why you refuse to answer @hjpotter92 comment?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, i am not understand what hjpotter92 trying to say?

Comment: @BANG click on the link he gave you. It will bring you to a web page. You will see something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BVSLp.png).  Scroll to the bottom of that page. You will see line saying "earned at least 200 reputation on X days". What is X in your case?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, this line you talking about earned at least 200 reputation on 1 days.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, what do you think, i have to earned “Mortarboard” badge or not?

Comment: OK, after some research I learned that only upvotes and bounties count towards the badge; You got 15 rep from answer being accepted so only 185 rep was counted towards the badge which isn't enough. :/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. After further investigation I found [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/894328/ahmed-masud?tab=reputation) who proved my theory wrong. You should have got the badge, so this is a bug.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I can't answer definitely (only a mod can), but it's possible that you downvoted an answer which was deleted on a subsequent day. So on that day your net reputation gain would have been only 199, but since the answer is now deleted it no longer shows in your reputation history. There may be other similar weird cases. Tick the “show removed posts” checkbox at the bottom of the reputation history: does it make any difference?

Comment: @Gilles, i tick “show removed posts” so you can check my reputation http://stackoverflow.com/users/718224/bang?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2013-05-20%2011:04:42Z&page=2

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I removed your bounty, as I don't wish to be seen farming meta rep :)

Comment: @Jarrod fair enough, but does it mean you look into the bug?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes, we're looking at it now.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, there is a bug.

On the day in question, you had gained 200 points, but had one answer with a downvote (net rep: 198).  The kicker is that you responsibly deleted this answer, which refunded the -2 from the downvote; however, *the badge logic doesn't take this refund into account.*

It was a known edge case, because a truly thorough check of *why* a user was refunded rep from a deleted post would slightly pain the database.

**To fix this, we have decided to ignore all rep changes due to downvotes** - whether you cast or receive them, they will no longer deduct from your daily total towards Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary.

Expect to see 350 new Mortarboard (including yours), 6 new Epic, and 4 new Legendary badges being granted in the next day!

Comment: Awesomeness in its best... you're surely on a roll here! :-)

Comment: @JarrodDixon, Thank You for your effort!!!

Comment: I just got one of the Epic badges, but I noticed the `/reputation` page still shows the old number of total days.  Will you guys be updating its logic?

Comment: @LanceRoberts yes, I'll take a look at it today.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, Thanks for "Mortarboard” badge.

Comment: @Jarrod did you take a look in the /reputation page? Looks like [it's still not showing properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181831/152859).