# Bad notification for the Mortarboard badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I gained no reputation recently on meta, I've even lost 50 yesterday.

Still I just got the notification *You've earned the "Mortarboard" badge* with a link to my meta badges.

Here's what I see in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation :

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 1 days
>   earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days

which seems a little fishy.

Had I had some activity recently I would have supposed I was voted then downvoted, or something like that, but as that's not the case, I conclude there might be some bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Congrats! You are one of 350 who got the badge retroactively as result of [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103/152859) by Jarrod.

To sum it up:

> To fix this, we have decided to **ignore all rep changes due to downvotes** - whether you cast or receive them, they will no longer deduct from your daily total towards Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary.

On Feb 6<sup>th</sup> you got more than 200 rep due to upvotes which is enough, as downvotes no longer matter.

As for reputation audit page not showing it, it was already [reported in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173381/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge/181103#comment550389_181103) I'll bump it.